# Is there a free Windows bulk JPEG background remover?

Tags: gratis, photography, editor, batch

I would like to find an unlimited free desktop or web-based tool that can input or upload a folder of JPEG images and remove the backgrounds, creating JPEG output retaining the height/width of the original image.

I have found many background removers, such as [Adobe's](https://www.adobe.com/express/feature/image/remove-background), but none meeting all the requirements of free, unlimited, batchable, JPEG in/out.

Answer (score 0):

I see you asked in the Photography exchange too, but they shut you down.  Too bad.

The following Python has worked well for me.  See [here regarding the available models.](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg)

```
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image

# start your loop here
input = Image.open('input.jpg')
output = remove(input) # has transparency
new_image = Image.new("RGBA", output.size, "WHITE") # create a white rgba background
new_image.paste(output, (0, 0), output) # paste the image on the background
new_image.convert('RGB').save(str(x)+'output.jpg', "JPEG")  # remove alpha, save as JPEG
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Paint 3D in Windows 11 with having many control options without installing additional software.. How to do is in [video](https://youtu.be/YD-dOpdvsg4).

On the other hand, sometimes you want to remove all the background and don't care about the resolution. You don't need any additional software and there are many websites that can fix this problem. Search for "remove background" on Google and you'll find dozens of them. Usually, there are restrictions in the free versions for sure. Personally, I recommend https://www.remove.bg, whose only drawback is lowering the resolution (around 500 x 500) which is fine for most cases.